# How can I hide the code coverage annotation in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unit-testing, code-coverage

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html) shows how to show the code coverage annotation (the bottom two images.) How can I hide it?
I tried it by unchecking Code Coverage checkbox, it didn't hide it right after unchecking it, furthermore I mustn't uncheck it as it's enabled in our git repository.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can hide show it from the menubar Editor->Hide Code Coverage

Comment: "Editor->Hide Code Coverage" option is not available in the Version Editor view, switch to the Standard Editor or Assistant Editor views to show/hide code coverage.

Comment: Perhaps that's the reason I didn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: Nice 
It was killing me :D

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 13.1 it's in `View -> Hide Code Review`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I **couldn't** find it in the `Editor` menu (*Xcode 10.1*);

[image: Editor Menu]

Found out later that it appeared while working on a **new file**.

So, if you can't find it, simply right-click on the `Sources` folder and choose `New File`, it should then show up as below;

[image]